# Squid random outgoing IP address on each request

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a server with 10 IPv4 addresses and I want Squid to randomly pick one of those IPv4 addresses for **each request**.

My current configuration for this is like:

```
acl random1 random 1/10
acl random2 random 1/10
acl random3 random 1/10
acl random4 random 1/10
acl random5 random 1/10
acl random6 random 1/10
acl random7 random 1/10
acl random8 random 1/10
acl random9 random 1/10
acl random10 random 1/10

tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.2 random1
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.3 random2
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.4 random3
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.5 random4
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.6 random5
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.7 random6
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.8 random7
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.9 random8
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.10 random9
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.11 random10
```

But this keeps repeating the main IPv4 address of the server like 96% of the requests.

Is there's anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you chose the random values, the probability to select each IP address follows a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). If you want to choose them uniformly, the probability of selecting an IP address (knowing the previous ones were discarded) must be `1/9` for the second, `1/8` for the third and so on:

```
acl random1 random 1/10
acl random2 random 1/9
acl random3 random 1/8
acl random4 random 1/7
acl random5 random 1/6
acl random6 random 1/5
acl random7 random 1/4
acl random8 random 1/3
acl random9 random 1/2

tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.2 random1
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.3 random2
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.4 random3
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.5 random4
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.6 random5
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.7 random6
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.8 random7
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.9 random8
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.10 random9
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.11
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it. But why we don't put a random ACL for the last IP address?

Comment: You can, but it should get selected with probability `100%`.